# gradle: how to test for different versions of dependencies?

Tags: java, build, gradle, dependency-management

i'm writing a library that has a runtime dependency on library X. it should work with different versions of library X. i want to run tests for explicitly specified versions or even for all version from Y up to the latest available in maven repository

is there any plugin that can help me or do i have to write everything from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a plugin that allows you to do that. It's pretty easy to write this yourself though. I'd set up a test case that calls off to the tooling API. The tooling API starts the build for a given `build.gradle` file. You can dynamically create the contents of the `build.gradle` file as part of your test setup. In your case you can iterate over a list of versions for your external dependency.

Comment: Have a look at the [org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnector](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/tooling/GradleConnector.html).

Comment: sorry, but i don't see how 'creating the content dynamically' will help me. at this point i don't know how to run tests 2 times for 2 specific different versions of library. each task (like `test`) is executed only once. and dependencies are set outside of `test` task. so i don't know how to execute tests two times with different dependencies

Comment: You'd implement different test cases in your test class. The build script you are invoking would have to be built dynamically. By that I mean that you have to create a new File with the build script contents needed (including you `dependencies` declaration). Test 1 uses version 1.0 of your dependency, test 2 uses version 2.0 of your dependency.